# Exclude folders from LG G6 stock gallery app

Tags: 7.0-nougat, photos, lg, gallery

I'm really enjoying the stock gallery app on my LG G6, but I can't find away to exclude folders (or "albums") from the default view.

This is really annoying, since it's showing album art and basically adds every music folder with album art in it to that view:

[image: LG G6 stock gallery app view with a lot of album art in it]

Does anyone know how I can hide those?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have option to exclude you can make it do that. Just use any file manager that can create file, and create file named ".nomedia" (without quotes) inside folder where are those images. However I think this will have side effects so music player may be unable to locate music in that folder if there is any also video too, but I'm not completely sure about it.